# Update row with Top 1 value per group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with sample data as below:

```
Name   | Code
Ken      Ken_A
Ken      Ken_B
Tim      Tim_1
Tim      Tim_3
Sam      Sam_Tens
Sam      Sam_Tenson
```

I want to do an update query that replaces the second instance of the Code ordered by Name with the first instance, so I would end up with the below:

```
Name   | Code
Ken      Ken_A
Ken      Ken_A
Tim      Tim_1
Tim      Tim_1
Sam      Sam_Tens
Sam      Sam_Tens
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use an updatable CTE with a join:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set code = tu2.code
    from toupdate join
         toupdate tu2
         on toupdate.name = tu2.name and
            tu2.seqnum = 1 and
            toupdate.seqnum > 1;
```

If you don't have a column that identifies the ordering of the rows, then your question doesn't make sense.  In SQL, tables are inherently unordered.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
update mytable 
set code = (select min(code) from mytable min_name where min_name.name = mytable.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query which uses correlated sub-queries:

```
UPDATE t1 SET Code = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Code FROM dbo.TableName t2
                      WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
                      ORDER BY Name, Code)
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TableName t2
       WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name) > 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3882/1/0)</kbd>